# Excel Formula - How do I write a formula to compare two cells and return the lowest value not to include zero?

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I write a formula to compare two cells and return the lowest value not to include zero?

Comment: if one of the cells is zero what to do

Answer (score 2):

Consider:

```
=IF(AND(A1=0,A2=0),"",IF(A1=0,A2,IF(A2=0,A1,MIN(A1,A2))))
```

- if **both** cells are zero, NULL is returned
- if **one** of the cells is zero, the other cell is returned
- if **neither** cell is zero, the minimum is returned

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula it works for multi cells

`=IF(AND(B2=0,B3=0),"",MIN(IF(B2:B3<>0,B2:B3,"")))`

Press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` at the same time it is an array formula
B2 first cell
B3 second cell

You can use also
`=IF(Min(B2,B3)=0,"",Min(B2,B3))`

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the response from Gary's Student is the only formula that worked for me.  Thank you so much!!!!
I have a worksheet that I created to assist lenders when compiling data that will add or subtract from a starting rate to return the best rate for our customer, but hit a hurdle when one of the fields has a zero value.

I have tested it and it works perfectly, Thank you again Gary's Student!!!

Comment: I'm going to guess that you posted the question as user706289.  You can interact on your thread but for your protection, you need to do it under the same user account used to post the question.  You can merge the two accounts via the "contact us" link at the bottom.  Answer posts are reserved for solutions.  The way to indicate that an answer was the solution is to accept it by clicking the ckeckmark next to it (from the original or merged user account).